# Android: Can't perform network operation on main thread

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

I'm trying to build an RSS reader for android.
Here is my code. I get error saying can't perform network operation on thread.

```
URL url = null;
try {
url = new URL((data.get(position).getThumbnail()));
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
InputStream content = null;
try {
content = (InputStream)url.getContent();
} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(content , "src"); 
Bitmap mIcon1 = null;
try {
mIcon1 =
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Details:
API is 16
I'm using XP pro , SP3.
Android os: Jelly Bean

Here is my logcat error:
http://pastebin.com/9wyVpNHV

Answer (score 3):

Correct. As of Android 4.0 (or perhaps 4.1), you automatically fail if you perform network I/O on the main application thread. Please move your above code to a background thread, such as an `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Thought it was 3.0 and up, but nonetheless +1. P.S. Great talks at the BBQ Mr. Murphy.

Comment: My code is running under loadingTask class
-----
new loadingTask().execute("http://feeds.feedburner.com/theappleblog");

Comment: @EGHDK: Possibly, but I do not recall hearing about it until 4.0. Then again, I am operating on very little sleep, so my brain is fuzzy. And thanks for the kind words!

Comment: @user461844: Then this code is not being called from `doInBackground()` -- otherwise, you would not get this exception.

Comment: here's some more of my code, can this be the problem?
http://pastebin.com/i3qDc98G

Comment: @user461844: As you can see from your stack trace, `EfficientAdapter` is what is triggering the network I/O. Since you need to perform the UI updates on the main application thread, you need to modify `EfficientAdapter` (or how you are using it) to not do network I/O itself, but instead allow you to handle the network I/O from `doInBackground()`.

Answer (score 2):

Use a thread and a handler to easily exchange data between UI thread and others threads

```
//Handler to send commands to UI thread
    Handler handler = new Handler();

    Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            URL url = null; 
            InputStream content = null;
            try { 
                url = new URL((data.get(position).getThumbnail())); 

                content = (InputStream)url.getContent();
                Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(content , "src");  
                final Bitmap mIcon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());; 

                handler.post(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        //here you can do everything in UI thread, like put the icon in a imageVew
                    }
                });

            } catch (Exception e) { 
                e.printStackTrace();
                handler.post(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(YourActivityName.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    }
                });
            } 


        }
    });
    th.start();
```

Comment: Like it better than AsyncTask, nice :)

Answer (score 0):

As said, on latests APIs network operations should be done in a separate thread or they will rise an exception. Here's some examples from the developer's site:

[Perform Network Operations on a Separate Thread](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html#AsyncTask)